# Where extra decimal points come at Number.prototype.toFixed

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I found `Number.prototype.toFixed()` can use to fixed the number to specific decimal point. It's can value between 0 to 20.
But when I make `(3.121212).toFixed(20)` it return 
`3.12121199999999987540`

Where these extra decimal points are come up?

Comment: Numbers in JS are floats, which are limited in precision. The same reason why `0.1 + 0.2 !== 0.3`.

Comment: Ok, so if that gonna be error, why is available to use to 20

Comment: It's not an "error". It's the result of limited precision when operating floats.

Comment: So I shouldn't used that if i want definite numbers.

Answer (score 1):

They come from the inherent lack of accuracy in binary representation of floating point numbers.